# Pasting multiple files directly into a webpage with Input tag

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I am rookie at web programming and I would like to know if the below is possible.

I want to be able to directly paste files into a webpage, which has the input tag, similar to the Outlook interface. I have seen posts which talk about drag and drop, but I wanted to know if this can be implemented.

I was thinking if this could be achieved via a Greasemonkey script/Firefox add on. I was thinking if we could somehow capture the paste event and check if the clipboard contains files, if it does we could probably use the location of the files and provide that as an input to the input element.

Do let me know if this can be done.

Thanks,

Comment: It can be done by writing an add-on; Greasemonkey cannot do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Javascript to update the filepath of a file input element, due to potential security issues.

Comment: The OP said: "via a Greasemonkey script/Firefox add on"

Comment: @Wladimir I may be wrong because I have no experience using it, but aren't Greasemonkey scripts written using (at least some) Javascript? Either way, the question has the javascript tag, and I know for a fact what he wants to do can't be done using it.

Comment: Yes, but *privileged* JavaScript can do a lot and lots of security restrictions don't apply here.

Comment: In this case, GM provides no extra functionality.  This answer is correct, files can't be pasted in, but they can be drag-and-dropped in.

Comment: Would this be possible via a firefox add on?

Comment: Yes, you could write an add-on that could do this.  That's somewhat more involved than a Greasemonkey script, though.